# ORA-00937: not a single-group group function for sum function

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to sum up the COUNT(IHID.RSID_PROD_N) by IHID.CS_ID but facing a problem. How to solve it?

```
SELECT 
  IHID.CS_ID ,IHID.RSID_PROD_N,COUNT(IHID.RSID_PROD_N),
  RSPF.RSPF_PROD_N,COUNT(RSPF.RSPF_PROD_N),sum(COUNT(IHID.RSID_PROD_N))
from IHIH 
JOIN IHID
  ON ihih.rsih_invoice_n = ihid.rsih_invoice_n AND ihih.cs_id = ihid.cs_id 
JOIN RSPF 
  ON ihih.cs_id = rspf.cs_id AND ihid.rsid_prod_n=rspf.rspf_prod_n
WHERE rspf_desc LIKE '%SCISSOR LIFT'
GROUP BY IHID.CS_ID, IHID.RSID_PROD_N,RSPF.RSPF_PROD_N,IHID.CS_ID;
```

The table is something like this

```
16     SJIII4626    1      SJIII4626    1
16     SJIII4632    1      SJIII4632    1
```

I want 1+1=2 for 16

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server? Those are two different animals.

Comment: Oracle generates Oracle errors, not MySQL or SQL Server.  I changed the tags.

Comment: You cannot nest aggregation functions.

Comment: @stickybit So how can I solve it?

Comment: I don't know. You failed to post enough information, especially an [mcve], that would be required to understand what you have and what you want here.

Comment: Agree with sticky bit.  What are you intending to do with sum(COUNT(IHID.RSID_PROD_N)).  Doesn't make sense.

Comment: The statement uses three different group functions: 2  COUNT functions and a SUM(COUNT..) This query need to be split into 3 different queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need analytic functions rather than aggregates here. Something like:

```
SELECT 
  IHID.CS_ID 
  ,IHID.RSID_PROD_N
  ,row_number() over (partition by IHID.CS_ID order by IHID.RSID_PROD_N) as IHID_RSID_PROD_N
  ,RSPF.RSPF_PROD_N
  ,row_number() over (partition by IHID.CS_ID order by RSPF.RSPF_PROD_N) as RSPF_RSPF_PROD_N
  ,COUNT(IHID.RSID_PROD_N) over (partition by IHID.CS_ID) as sum_count
from IHIH 
JOIN IHID
  ON ihih.rsih_invoice_n = ihid.rsih_invoice_n AND ihih.cs_id = ihid.cs_id 
JOIN RSPF 
  ON ihih.cs_id = rspf.cs_id AND ihid.rsid_prod_n=rspf.rspf_prod_n
WHERE rspf_desc LIKE '%SCISSOR LIFT'
;
```

Not entirely sure because your question lacks a complete test case.

If this answer isn't quite what you want please **edit your question** to provide table structures and sample input data together with required output derived from that data.

Answer (score 0):

Its not grouping as you would like because of the unique values in IHID.RSID_PROD_N and  RSPF.RSPF_PROD_N.  Remove those columns and it will group as expected.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use your current query (almost unchanged) as a CTE, and then apply `SUM` to a `COUNT` which you couldn't have done in a nested manner. Something like this:

```
with your_current_query as
  -- removed nested SUM(COUNT)
  (select 
     ihid.cs_id,
     ihid.rsid_prod_n,
     rspf.rspf_prod_n,
     count(ihid.rsid_prod_n) cnt_rsid
     count(rspf.rspf_prod_n) cnt_rspf
   from ihih join ihid on ihih.rsih_invoice_n = ihid.rsih_invoice_n 
              and ihih.cs_id = ihid.cs_id 
             join rspf on ihih.cs_id = rspf.cs_id 
              and ihid.rsid_prod_n=rspf.rspf_prod_n
   where rspf_desc like '%SCISSOR LIFT'
   group by ihid.cs_id, 
            ihid.rsid_prod_n,
            rspf.rspf_prod_n
  )
select cs_id,
       rsid_prod_n,
       rspf_prod_n,
       cnt_rsid,
       cnt_rspf,
       sum(cnt_rsid) sum_cnt_rsid   --> this represents nested SUM(COUNT)
from your_current_query
group by cs_id,
         rsid_prod_n,
         rspf_prod_n,
         cnt_rsid,
         cnt_rspf;
```